# Black hole, ingoing light-like and causality

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, causality, geodesics

In Kruskal-Szekerers coordinates, for example, I've noticed that ingoing light-like trajectories, in the interval $ 0<r<r_s$, are decreasing in time $t$ so they travel in the past for an observator in $r= \infty$, this fact don't break causality?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't globally define simultaneity or globally define a time coordinate $t$. It also appears like you're talking about the Schwarzschild $t$ and $r$ coordinates, which don't really make sense to use within the horizon $r_s$. We use the new timelike and spacelike coordinates $T$ and $R$, which are given explicitly on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Szekeres_coordinates). These are defined on the whole spacetime and they keep their timelike and spacelike characters respectively.

You can also note that within $r<r_{s}$, in the Schwarzschild coords, the $t$ coordiante becomes spacelike and the $r$ coordinate becomes timelike, so the singularity at $r=0$ is actually a future singularity. Hence worldlines/trajectories within the horizon don't travel into the past (which is only defined locally anyway).

Comment: Ok, but in this diagram if I have, in II zone, an outgoing light ray its travel in the future ( t became higher) but for an ingoing light  ray why  I don't have t decreasing?

Comment: Yes, in zone II $t$ isn't a timelike coordinate, so it doesn't correspond with 'future' or 'past' like you're referring to.

Comment: Also there are no 'outgoing' rays in zone II. All rays are are ingoing. They all move in the increasing $T$ direction (the y-axis on the Kruskal diagram), towards the singularity at $r=0$.

Comment: Ok, but light-cones still have the same meaning?

Comment: The Kruskal diagram is a conformal diagram, so lightcones are still at 45 degrees, yes. I'd advise looking over the Wikipedia page for these details, so these comments don't become a longer discussion. Also it's important to be sure of the meaning of the coordinates, i.e. the Kruskal series introduces new coordinates $T$ and $X$.

Comment: Inside the black hole ( II zone) what physical meaning has the time coordinate t?

Comment: As I said, it's not a time coordinate. Please see my previous comments and also in my answer: "the  coordiante becomes spacelike and the  coordinate becomes timelike". The wikipedia page explains this all, so we should stop this discussion.